# $\delta$ proof of a limit at a point

Tags: real-analysis

problem: Evaluate the following limits or show they do not exist.
I'm stuck on trying to show  $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x}{x-1} (x\neq 1)$ does not exist.

I proved that $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{x}{x-1} (x\neq 1)=\infty$

Proof:

> Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha>0$. Let $\delta=\frac{1}{\alpha}$ such that if $0<x-1<\delta\implies \frac{1}{x-1}>\delta=\alpha$. Since $x>1$ it follows that $\frac{x}{x-1}>\frac{1}{x-1}$. Thus $\frac{x}{x-1}>\frac{1}{x-1}>\alpha$

Now I want to show $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{x}{x-1} (x\neq 1)=-\infty$

Proof:

> Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $\delta= \frac{1}{1+|\alpha|}$ such that if $0<1-x<\frac{1}{1+|\alpha|}\implies x-1>-\frac{1}{1+|\alpha|}\implies \frac{1}{x-1}<-(1+|\alpha|)<\alpha$. Thus  $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{x}{x-1} (x\neq 1)=-\infty$

Conclusion: Since $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{x}{x-1} \neq \lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{x}{x-1}\implies \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x}{x-1}$ DNE

Would this be correct?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: At this point, it looks pretty much fine, though it doesn't matter that $\frac1{x-1}<\alpha.$ Rather, since $\frac1{x-1}<-(1+|\alpha|),$ then we have $$\frac{x}{x-1}=\frac{(x-1)+1}{x-1}=1+\frac1{x-1}<1+-(1+|\alpha|)=-|\alpha|\le\alpha,$$ and so we're done.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment.

Comment: You are welcome, but I just noticed an error! Take a look and see what you think.

Comment: oh if $x=1$ then it becomes undefined.

Comment: Should i then put $\delta=min(\frac{1}{1+|\alpha|},\frac{1}{4})$

Comment: Ok i fixed it up. I hope its all correct now.

Comment: oh thanks that helped quite a bit. I'm curious  with what could be the issue with $\frac{1}{1+|\alpha|}$?.

Comment: Upon further thinking about it, there's nothing wrong with $\delta=\frac1{1+|\alpha|}.$ Your pointing out that $\frac1{x-1}<\alpha,$ while true, threw me off the scent of how that $\delta$ was coming into play. It looks almost perfect now.

Comment: oh and one last thing for $\alpha$ we are allowed to pick how big $\alpha$ should be like say we want $\alpha>2$ could we do that?

Comment: That depends. If we're trying to show that a function increases without bound in some limit (as in your first proof), then it suffices to show that for any $\alpha>2,$ $f(x)$ will eventually be greater than $\alpha$ as $x$ [does whatever limiting behavior it's doing]. This is because it follows that for any $\alpha,$ $f(x)$ will eventually be greater than $\alpha$. That *wouldn't* work on your second proof, since we want to show that $f(x)$ is eventually less than any given $\alpha,$ and transitivity of inequality wouldn't apply. However, we could show that it worked for $\alpha<2,$ there.

Comment: @CameronBuie I think we just need to show that if $|x| \gt 1$, then given any $M \gt 0$, we can always find an $\delta \gt 0$ such that $\left|\frac{x}{x-1}\right| \gt M$. It implies that no matter what value of $x/(x-1)$ would be at interval $-1 \lt x \lt 1$, its value will ultimately goes to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ .

Comment: @sundaycat: That's a fair point, but many texts would say (for example) that the limit of $\frac1{x^2}$ as $x\to 0$ exists, just not as a real number. If the OP's text is such a one, then simply knowing that $\left|\frac x{x-1}\right|$ increases without bound as $x\to 1$ isn't enough.

Comment: @user60887: It's worth taking a look at sundaycat's point. If your text adopts the convention that infinite limits are said to exist (in a sense), then you should proceed as you did. Otherwise, it is enough to know that one of your one-sided limits is infinite, so that the limit does not exist (since it is not a real number).

Comment: My book states that limit call if $L$ is a real number if it exists. I'm using the book by Bartle and Sherbert.

Comment: @user60887 So in that case, even though we can see that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1{x^2}=+\infty,$$ we would say that the limit does not exist. Does that accord with your definition? If so, then that makes your life easier, since you only have to prove that $\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{x}{x-1}=+\infty,$ since the limit does not exist *regardless* of whether the left-hand limit agrees.

Comment: Oh I think I would have to show that the limit $\frac{1}{x^2}$ as $x\rightarrow 1^-$ as well to.

Comment: @user60887: Well, anyway, it certainly doesn't hurt to prove that. I would definitely confirm that convention, if possible, because it would save you some grief down the road. On another topic, I still don't see why you would choose $$\delta=\min\left\{\frac1{1+|\alpha|},\frac14\right\}$$ for your second proof. Where is it that the $\frac14$ is coming into play?

Comment: @user60887: Okay, I see that you've added the definition. How are one-sided limits defined?

Comment: +1, I share the same confusion with Cameron. How does the 1/4 come from?

Comment: Ok ill add that too and I was not sure why i put the $\frac{1}{4}$. I think I wanted to not let $x=1$.

Comment: @user60887: That was taken care of by $0<1-x.$

Comment: Yeah I edited it out and I put up how the book defines left and right hand limits it they exist as a real number.

Comment: @user60887: So I see. Well, based on the definitions, it is certainly suggestive that the book may want limits to be real numbers in order to say that they exist, but to see that for sure, you should read carefully through the section on infinite limits, and see if they discuss it there. Alternately, ask your professor what convention you should use.

Comment: Yeah I added the infinite one as well. But there lots of different definitions i suppose in different books. But from the looks of my proof I think it suffices.

Comment: @user60887: It certainly suffices. Once again, well done!

Comment: Thanks for you help though.